# Strange behaviour of the Cinemachine virtual camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using the `new input system` in my unity project. I also use `Cinemachine`. I use `Cinemachine Input Provider` to change the input from the old to the new system.
When I change `max speed` to `Input Value Gain` in speed field of virtual camera's settings (I did it because it is the most comfortable way to control camera) I face a problem.
My problem: When my character moves after some time the camera speed changes. If I start to move in the opposite direction, the camera speed returns to normal.
This is independent of the other components in the scene. My scene has only plane, cube, camera and my character.

Here's my character control code (ignore the awful calculation of movement direction):

```
private Rigidbody _rb;

private Vector2 _moveDirection;

private float speed = 5f;

private void Awake()
{
    _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
}

public void OnMove(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    _moveDirection = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    Move(_moveDirection);
}

private void Move(Vector3 moveDirection)
{
    float scaledMoveSpeed = speed * Time.deltaTime;

    moveDirection = new Vector3(Camera.main.transform.forward.x, 0, Camera.main.transform.forward.z).normalized  * moveDirection.y + new Vector3(Camera.main.transform.right.x, 0, Camera.main.transform.right.z).normalized * moveDirection.x;
    _rb.MovePosition(transform.position + moveDirection * scaledMoveSpeed);
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the camera settings and `Cinemachine Input Provider`:

[image]

And screenshots of the `Input Actions` settings:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for those who will ever face this problem! On your `main camera`, in the `CinemachineBrain` component, change the `Update Method` from `Smart Update` to `Late Update`. That should help